# Tag 'Android' junto com 'Java'

Tags: debate, tags

Não sei ao certo como a comunidade e do SOpt se estrutura / modera. Porém, ultimamente tenho notado uma enorme quantidade de questões relacionadas a API do Android, apenas. E apesar dela ser feito Java, na maioria dos casos, são apenas usuários que tem problemas de layout por exemplo ou qualquer coisa relaciona apenas a API em sí.
Um programador Java em alguns casos poderia até colaborar, porém na maioria das vezes somente quem têm vivência com a API poderia efetivamente ajudar. Dito isso, em alguns casos temos quase uma pagina toda apenas com perguntas referente a Android, oque atrapalha para identificar questões reais sobre Java propriamente dito.

Qual a melhor prática para esses casos ? deveriam os usuários que querem fazer uma pergunta específica de Android, não usar 'Java' nas tags ?

Comment: Só para deixar claro: em geral estabelecemos uma política oficial do site para manter um padrão. Nenhum usuário que fizer diferente estará errado, não merecerá qualquer punição ao mesmo tempo que nenhum usuário que editar para cumprir essa recomendação de estilo também estará errado. Vamos estabelecer um padrão seja ele qual for, e tentemos segui-lo. De qualquer forma sempre caberá interpretação individual quando cabe só das *tags* ou quando cabe ambas.

Comment: O *tagueameanto* errado não é um problema muito sério mas é um dos principais problemas do site. Grande parte das perguntas tem tags erradas por excesso ou absência. Mas é um problema difícil de resolver. Eu mesmo fico em dúvida em muitos casos. A única coisa que podemos fazer é tentar estabelecer padrões, conscientizar os usuários mais ativos, mostrar que os membros de sub-comunidades (representadas pelas *tags*) sejam mais ativos pelo menos na melhor taxinomia dos assuntos que lhe interessam. Parece que alguns usuários se sentem constrangidos em editar. Esse é o trunfo do site.

Comment: Se tem certeza do que está fazendo, pode editar sem dó.

Comment: Creio que se a pergunta se relacione com Android e Java, precisa das duas tags. Já deu uma olhada nas suas preferências, na opção "tags ignoradas"? Talvez sirva para você filtrar o que não interessa (não testei, mas pode ser um caminho). Na barra da direita da lista de perguntas tem um "editar", do lado de **tags favoritas**, que abre opção para **tags ignoradas** também.

Comment: O @brasofilo tá bem correto. São duas questões diferentes. A gente precisa encontrar um padrão, mas colocá-lo em prática é responsabilidade de todo mundo, não só de quem pergunta. Mas, minha impressão (admitidamente leiga), é que no caso de Android e Java, não vai dar pra traçar uma linha definitiva o suficiente... Acho que vai ter sempre que ser lidado caso a caso.