# Afinal a tag Android deve ser acompanhada de Java ou não?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Apesar de ter [esta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2213/tag-android-junto-com-java), este é um caso que, volta e meia, tenho um pouco de dúvida sobre perguntas envolvendo Android, e a outra pergunta acabou sem um debate interessante ajudando a definir isso.

Há algum tempo vi muitas edições feitas removendo, por considerar que Android é Java, porém, no começo deste ano, foi levado pro *chat* essa questão, e a opinião da maioria na época foi de que não deveriam andar juntas, pois há outras ferramentas para Android que não necessariamente dependem de conhecimento em java.

Para termos uma definição registrada e até para resolver essa dúvida que as vezes acaba voltando(com certa razão), questiono:

Android deve ser acompanhado de Java quando for possível identificar esta linguagem? Ou nestes casos, subtendemos a *tag*?

Answer (score 14):

Não devem andar juntas, mas podem andar juntas. Então colocar [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) junto de [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) é algo que deve ser contextual. Eu acho que sempre que o Java faz parte da pergunta a *tag* deveria estar na na pergunta e se tem alguém tirando, acho que está cometendo um erro e excluindo a comunidade Java que deve ter interesse naquilo.

Seria um erro achar que [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) pressupõe que está falando de Java e por isso não precisa da *tag* adicional. Quem acha isso deve pensar que só existe Java para rodar em Android e ignora as demais tecnologias.

Um erro comum que eu vejo é usar [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) onde não tem nada de Android na pergunta. Por acaso ele está fazendo algo para esta plataforma, mas a pergunta é genérica da linguagem.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, um exemplo é uma pergunta que trata do android mas não tem nada haver com java, e sim com os styles que é mais xml, logo se usaria as tags  android-xml/android-layout(dependendo do caso) ao invés da tag java, o que daria mais sentido a pergunta.

Comment: A questão surgiu porque o @diegofm alterou uma questão incrementando a _tag_ JAVA em uma questão que só tinha a _tag_ ANDROID. Então fiquei pensando se vale mesmo apena alterar uma questão pra inserir a _tag_. Ai pensei também: "Será que eu tenho que alterar todas as minhas questões ou deixo como está?" Desde o começo, eu sempre inseri somente a _tag_ Android, e nunca o Java.